# Using 'int' when declaring functions in matlab

Tags: function, matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to define a function that looks a bit like this:

```
function u = expectedutility(x)
u = int(utility(x,I)*density(I),I,-10,10)

function t = utility(x,I)
m = x+I
if m>=0 u = m^(1/2)
else u = -2*((-m)^(1/2))

end
end
function s = density(I)
s = 1/20
end

end
```

In the example above I have used a uniform distribution with upper bound 10 and lower bound -10, but I would like to be able to generalise it so that the function density(I) could be any pdf for a random variable I. Also I understand that i could have used piecewise(.) to specify utility but I am using 2016a so it isn't on my version of Matlab.

Basically my problem is that whenever i hit `"expectedutility(2)"` I get the error

```
"Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'."
```

I should like 'int' to integrate the function with respect to I, plug in -10 and 10 say and then allow me to observe u for different x values.

Comment: are you maybe looking for `integral`?

Comment: Well I am looking to numerically integrate a function of multiple variables with respect to one of those variables. This would give me an answer in terms of many different variables, and I thought numerical integration was only for giving numerical answers?

Comment: There is nothing in the code you provided that makes it non-numeric.

Comment: I am afraid I don't quite understand what you mean - in the second linee of my code I would expect to get an expression that is in terms of a variable,x, rather than just a number. Hence the expression is not numeric - perhaps I am using the word 'numeric' incorrectly? In either case, if i can use the function "integrate" to resolve my issue I would be grateful to see how.

Comment: You say "I hit `expectedutility(2)` and I get the error". if `x` is symbolic, then you should define as such. If you do `expectedutility(2)` then `x=2`, thus numeric. Because.... 2 is a number...

Answer (score 1):

You have several things wrong in your code, but what I think you are trying to do is integrate a function that has a symbolic variable `I` and a numeric variable `x`.

The main problem in your code is that you have not defined `I` at all. However, even if you do so, you have a secondary problem: conditionals are not allowed in symbolic functions. There is an alternative to this, which is using the `heaviside` function.

If you define your `utility` function as:

```
function u=utility(x,I)
m = x+I;
u = m^(1/2)*heaviside(m); % for positives
u =u + -2*( (-m)^(1/2) )*heaviside(-m);    % for negatives  
end
```

then you can call:

```
density=1/20;
syms I;
x=2;
u = int(utility(x,I)*density,I,-10,10)
```

and it gives:

```
u=
  (4*3^(1/2))/5 - (16*2^(1/2))/15
```

and to get the numerical result you just call `double(u)`

```
ans =

  -0.1229
```

---

If you don't want separate functions, just do:

```
density=1/20;
syms I;
x=2;

m = x+I;
u = m^(1/2)*heaviside(m); % for positives
u =u + -2*( (-m)^(1/2) )*heaviside(-m);    % for negatives 

uint = int(u*density,I,-10,10)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not just trying to integrate the function as you say. I would like to specify the function using the int command. Is there a way to specify the density, and to integrate u = utility(x,I)*density(I) with respect to I, so that I might be able to call utility(x) as a function in the command window?

Comment: You can always write your own functions without the `function` keyword. I mean, you can literally copy the code, put it on your script. I used a function because you used one, no need of one. @HugoLu. However you can not "specify the function using the `int` command" as `int` only integrates. See the update

Comment: Update: I utilised heaviside in place of my IF ELSE function and now I have managed to get what I wanted. Thank you very much. It is a real pain not having 'piecewise'  in my package!!

Answer (score 0):

The `int` function for integer don't take any double data type for input. You must use `syms x` (symbolic scalar variable) to make it compatible. You can check [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html). Another issue with the code is that variable `I` is undefined.

Comment: While this may be the answer, please try to format it properly and add the relevant code to fix the problem

Comment: your requirement is unclear. It can't be reformatted. define the input variables to function and 'int' in proper format

Comment: My requirement is for you to write a properly stated and written answer. I am not the original asker, I am just trying to teach you how to write a good quality answer.